# ios login screen issue

Tags: ios, json, parsing, authentication, uiviewcontroller

I've been developing an iOS app that includes a login screen. This screen has two `UITextField` where I input the username and the password.

Now, the issue recalls in the following: I've set up an "else if" to trigger an `UIAlertView` if the field are in blank.

The `UIAlertView` DOES pop up but... in the next View Controller.

Another issue is... It check if the username and the password are right or not and it jumps into the next View Controller as well.

This is odd because I set an "if" condition to check that the text in both `UITextFields` must match in order to trigger the next View Controller.

I've got the hunch that another method linked to the login action might be interfering in the process.

I will post the segment of the code concerning the login:

```
- (void)btn_submit:(id)sender{
    NSString *user = self.usuari.text;
    NSString *pass = self.contrasenya.text;

    NSString * urlBase = @"http://www.v2msoft.com/clientes/lasalle/curs-ios/login.php?username=lluis&password=seguro";

    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:urlBase completion:^(id json,JSONModelError *err){

JsonUser * user = [[JsonUser alloc]initWithDictionary:json error:nil];

        if(user.succeed){
            self.user_id = user.user_id;

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:self];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
    }];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


    if (([self.usuari.text isEqualToString:@"lluis"]) && ([self.contrasenya.text isEqualToString:@"seguro"])){

        Supermarket * supermercat = segue.destinationViewController;
        supermercat.user_id = self.user_id;

    }

    else if (_usuari.text.length == 0 || _contrasenya.text.length == 0)
    {

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alerta!"
                                    message:@"Camps buits!"
                                   delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil
          ] show];
    }

}
```

And, also, the few lines of the "JsonUser" class:

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@interface JsonUser : JSONModel

@property BOOL succeed;
@property int user_id;
```

I think that I might be making a mistake by sending the parameters to the server through the URL and that might override the login.

I'd appreciate any help or advice regarding this matter.

Comment: Yikes, watch out! You're sending your username and password credentials unencrypted over the internet.

Comment: Check that you haven't linked a segue directly from your submit button in IB.  Also, yes, use HTTPS

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the warning. But since this is not a professional app (it's college homework) then it doesn't matter much. It's not meant to be installed on a device. It's only meant to be simulated. And the data only works to access a json file in a remote server so no harm done. Thanks for the warning, though.

Comment: @Paulw11: "btn_submit" is defined as IBAction on "Logger.h": but it's a "received action" in the link list of my View Controller. The segue is linked from one VC to the other.

Answer (score 0):

It is already too late for your check within `prepareForSegue`. If you had the chance to stop the presentation of the segue there the method would be called shouldPresentSegue or something like that. Perform your check (the `else if`) before you call `performSegue`.

Comment: Yes - You can implement the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW111

Answer (score 0):

whether u connect segue from submit button to next view controller or segue from login view to nextviewcontroller. Make Sure your segue only from login screen to nextviewcontroller not from submit button.

Comment: I did check that and the segue only links both View Controller: the button doesn't link.